# Display PDF in browser (except pdf.js and Adobe Reader plugin)

Tags: pdf, browser

I try to find solutions for display PDF in browser.

A couple of restrictions:

- PDF should be downloaded to client as-is. Conversion like PDF -> HTML on server is not allowed.
- Installation of additional software, like browser plugins is not allowed. But it is assumed, that user has widespread plugins, like Flash, Adobe reader ...

I know about next solutions:

- Adobe Reader plugin.
- PDF.js
- FlexPaper (but not sure if it render pdf on on client side or convert PDF to series of Flash objects...)

What you can advice else?

== UPDATE
More possible solutions are:

- Silverlight component
- JavaApplet component

Comment: Are there any additional requirements, such as the need for submitting data? The most straightforward approach would be letting the user's configuration decide what to use (which may be Adobe Reader (via plug-in), or the respective browser's PDF viewer).

Comment: Yes, we has some additional requirement. The most important - some portion of text should be highlighted. So we can't allow to user select arbitrary viewer. Selected PDF viewer (or may be several for different browsers) will be somehow modified/tuned for support highlighting. But currently I looking for every possible solution.

Comment: You pretty much listed all your choices above based on your restrictions :) (Just add Chrome's Foxit Viewer to the list near Adobe Reader plugin)